# Koa-handlebars: Unable to render view: The partial could not be found

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js, template-engine

```
// project/layouts/main.hbs

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
    {{{@body}}}
</body>
</html>


// project/views/home-public.hbs

{{> nav-public}}
<div class="container">
    <div class="starter-template">
        <h1>Home Public</h1>
        <p class="lead">This is my home.</p>
    </div>
</div>


// project/partials/nav-public.hbs

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Example</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="/">Journey</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="/">Departures</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="about" style="margin-left:1em">About</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="/signout">Sign in</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Node code that runs:

```
app.use(handlebars({
    defaultLayout: 'main'
}));

app.use(function* () {
    yield this.render('home-public', {
        user: {
            email: "name@example.com"
        }
    });
});
```

I can't see what's wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you or something else registering the partials with code such as `hbs.registerPartials(__dirname + '/partials');`?

Answer (score 1):

This one caught me out at first, too. The reason is that you're using hyphens and/or path separators in your `{{> partial-name}}` calls, which seems reasonable when you're coming from express-handlebars. The answer is in the documentation:

> partialId(file)
>
> This function is a little backwards compared to layouts and views, but it takes a path for a partial template file. (relative to partialsDir) and converts it into a handlebars-friendly identifier.
>
> For example: "navigation.hbs" => "navigation"
>
> **By default, it will strip the extension and camel-case the remaining string.**
>
> **For example: "nav/main.hbs" => "navMain"**

So basically, by default it's going to translate your partial path completely into camelCaseForHyphensAndDirectorySlashes, for example `example/my-partial` would require a partial call of `{{> exampleMyPartial }}`.

This is fortunately fairly easy to customise if you prefer to use a partial name that actually represents your partial's file path. Here's the config I use (I use the strip-extension module to get rid of the file extension):

```
var stripExtension = require('strip-extension');
app.use(koaHandlebars({
  partialId: function(file) {
      // Note: the .replace below is just to normalise windows paths, you
      // may not need it.
      return stripExtension(file).replace('\\', '/');
  }
});
```